# tensorflow error while training model - Labels dtype should be integer Instead got <dtype: 'string'>

Tags: pandas, tensorflow

I am currently learning tensorflow and am new to the concept.  I am trying a multi-class classification using LinearClassifier

I have a dataset where I have reduced the number of input variables using PCA to 30.  I have named the PCA columns as PCA_Col_0 -- PCA_Col_29.  The PCA was done using scikit learn

I then created tensorflow feature column for each of the 30 variables using the following code:

```
feat_cols = [PCA_Col_0, .... PCA_Col_29]
d = {}
for item in feat_cols:
    d[item] = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(item)

feat_cols2 = list(d.values())
```

I then initialized the model

```
import tensorflow as tf
n_classes = 3914
model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns = feat_cols2, n_classes = n_classes) 
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x = DF_Final_V1[feat_cols], y = DF_Final_V1['nUnique_ID'], shuffle = False)
model.train(input_fn)
```

I get the error  Labels dtype should be integer Instead got  on tensorflow

I have verified the following:

1. The Input dataset has only float64 entries
2. There are no null or nan values in the input dataset
3. the tf.feature_column shows dtype as float32

Why isn't my model training and why am I getting this error?

Comment: Did you check the type of the variable you are trying to predict ?

Comment: Hi, the variable was a float variable

Comment: Try converting/formating your target variable to an integer, from TF documentation "note that class labels are integers representing the class index (i.e. values from 0 to n_classes-1)."

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late update, yes you were right.  This worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @Bruce Swain in the comments.

The code worked after I modified the output value from 0 to n_classes -1